# Numpy ndarray holding string with unknown data type

Tags: python, numpy

I ran the following code in a jupyter notebook cell

```
ndarrs=np.array(["1.2","1.5","1.6"], dtype=np.string_)

print(ndarrs.dtype)
```

It returned `|S3` as shown below.

Can someone help me understand the meaning of this symbol?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, you shouldn't really specify the `np.string_` dtype, as it is left there for backwards compatibility with Python 2. The `S` type you see using `np.dtype` is a map to the `bytes_` type, a zero-terminated string buffer, which shouldn't be used.

The `S` just means `string` and the number gives the number of bytes.

```
In [1]: s = ""        # start with an empty string                                                                                                

In [2]: for i in range(5):    # make the string larger
            s += str(i) 
            a = np.array([s], dtype=np.string_) 
            print(f"{a}\t{a.dtype}") 
                                                                                                                       
    [b'0']  |S1
    [b'01'] |S2
    [b'012']    |S3
    [b'0123']   |S4
    [b'01234']  |S5
    [b'012345'] |S6
```

For python 3 you should instead use `np.unicode`:

```
In [1]: a = np.array(["hello", "world"], dtype=np.unicode)                                                             

In [2]: type(a)                                                                                                       
Out[2]: numpy.ndarray

In [3]: b.dtype                                                                                                       
Out[3]: dtype('<U5')
```

- `<` means [*little-endian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)
- `U` means a unicode string
- `5` relates to the number of bytes used to hold the string. If you had really long strings, that number would then increase.

Have a look at [this documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), which states:

> Note on string types:
>
> For backward compatibility with Python 2 the S and a typestrings remain zero-terminated bytes and np.string_ continues to map to np.bytes_. To use actual strings in Python 3 use U or np.unicode_.

Comment: Thanks that was really useful !!!